# Open Tab on Page Load - Javascript

Tags: javascript, tabs

I've 3 tabs that use javascript to show content when they are clicked:

```
<ul class="tab">
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, '12_Weeks')">12 Weeks</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, '4_Weeks')">4 Weeks</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, '1_Week')">1 Week</a></li>
</ul>
```

Divs are placed in my html code as follows:

```
<div id="12_Weeks" class="tabcontent"> <!-- Tab 1 starts here -->
<h1>Example Text</h1>
</div>
```

I'd like the first tab to be open when the page is loaded and have tried the following code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  $("#12_Weeks").trigger('click');
});
```

however this doesn't seem to do the trick, anyone know what I'm doing wrong here, am sure it's super simple!?

Comment: What does `openCity` look like? What is the `event` argument?

Comment: Nice, needed to add openCity("12_Weeks"), they left this bit out at W3schools, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is an element with ID #12_weeks on your page?
It is not present in your sample code.

Comment: Ok, it seems that you are triggering the click on the wrong element. The click-handler that you are trying to trigger is on the <LI>, but you are triggering the click on the <DIV> itself, which does not have a click-event attached.

Comment: Ok, do you know how i solve this and trigger the click on the click-handler?

Comment: $( document ).ready(function() {
  $('ul.tab li:first > a.tablinks').trigger('click');
});

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger click has tab content but it will be in tab title. See flowing code.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  $('ul#tab li:first > a.tablinks').trigger('click');
});
```

Or 
you can user this under your hide execute code. $("#12_Weeks").show('');

Comment: you can user this under your hide execute code. $("#12_Weeks").show('');

Answer (score 0):

Seems I needed to add openCity("12_Weeks") in my javascript function, they seem to have left this bit out at W3schools, thanks all for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `style="display: block;"` directly in your default `<div></div>` tag, like this:

```
<div id="12_Weeks" class="tabcontent" style="display: block;"> <!-- Tab 1 starts here -->
<h1>Example Text</h1>
</div>
```

When a different Tab is clicked, the `style="display: none;"` and the current clicked Tab is given `style="display: block;"`

This should do the trick.